# Parallelize the addition of a vector of matrices in OPENMP

Tags: c++, matrix, openmp, eigen

I have a STL Vector containing some Matrices such as this

std::vector foovec;

There are approximately 3000 entries in this vector that I want to add up and form a new Eigen::Matrix.

The naive C++ code to do this would be :

```
for(int i = 0; i <foovec.size();i++) {
      result +=  foovec[i];
  }
```

However I want to parallelize this operation using OPENMP. I know I cant use the reduction pragma since this is a non-scalar type. If anyone can tell me a good way to parallelize this reduction without any write conflicts, that would be great.

Comment: Being that Eigen uses lazy evaluation, I'm not sure that at any given point in the loop `result` actually contains a calculated result. You can enforce that by using `.noalias()` on `result` and compare performance. Regardless, I assume that you don't  want to divide the calculation by hand into sections, and are only interested in a single pragma, maybe with a few more lines. Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: You need to provide a better code example. What is the type of `result` (you say it's not a scalar but then what is it) and `foovec`.

Comment: @Zboson Presumably, `result` is an object of type `Eigen::Matrix<...>` (see two lines above the code).

Comment: @AviGinsburg, good point, it's in the title and text as well. I really wish people would put it in the code though since it's more readable to me than parsing text. So the OP wants the sum of matrices. That's going to be memory bandwidth bound.

Comment: @Zboson Yes, but when using the default defines and full optimizations, it's fully vectorized in addition to the lazy evaluation, so not as bad as it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
//std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, n, m>> foovec;
#pragma omp parallel
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, n, m> result_private; 
    #pragma omp for nowait //fill result_private in parallel
    for(int i=0; i<foovec.size(); i++) result_private += foovec[i];
    #pragma omp critical
    result += result_private; 
}
```

For OpenMP >=4.0 you can also do this

```
#pragma omp declare reduction (merge : Eigen::Matrix<double, n, m> : omp_out += omp_in)

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(merge: result)
for(int i=0; i<foovec.size(); i++) result += foovec[i];
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted.. Not to mention comes with a nice performace boost too... Accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

For me, using `reduction(merge : ...)` did not work.  It had problems with uninitialized matrices (I think).

The following did:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction( \
                +: \
                Eigen::Matrix3d: \
                omp_out= omp_out + omp_in) \
                initializer(omp_priv=Eigen::Matrix3d::Zero())

Eigen::Matrix3d sum = Eigen::Matrix3d::Zero();
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix3d> elems;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: sum)
for (size_t i = 0; i < elems.size(); ++i) {
    sum += elems[i];
}
```